# How to get sprint details based on matched domain & project from two collections?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm trying to get the unique sprint list based on comparing two collections list.
I have two different mongoDB collections like user & levels.
In levels collections have a data like below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596e69d2a2e6f23e28b9fa51"),
    "domain" : "Domain1",
    "project" : "Project1",
    "sprint" : "Default",
    "uniqueId" : 1001
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596e69d3a2e6f23e28b9fa6b"),
    "domain" : "Domain1",
    "project" : "Project1",
    "sprint" : "Sprint1",
    "uniqueId" : 1002
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596e69d3a2e6f23e28b9fa6b"),
    "domain" : "Domain2",
    "project" : "Project1",
    "sprint" : "Sprint2",
    "uniqueId" : 1003
}
/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596e69d3a2e6f23e28b9fa6b"),
    "domain" : "Domain2",
    "project" : "Project2",
    "sprint" : "Sprint1",
    "uniqueId" : 1004
}
```

User collection will be like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598aa6d9c09aee30cdda1065"), 
    "userId" : "TestUser",
    "password" : "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99",
    "isActive" : true,
    "selectedProjects" : [ 
        {
            "domainName" : "Domain1",
            "projectName" : "Project1"
        }, 
        {
            "domainName" : "Domain2",
            "projectName" : "Project1"
        }, 
        {
            "domainName" : "Domain2",
            "projectName" : "Project2"
        }, 
        {
            "domainName" : "Domain3",
            "projectName" : "Project4"
        }
    ]
}
```

testService.java, This way only i took the project details from user collection

```
@GET
@Path("/projectdetail")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getprojectDetail(@QueryParam("userName") String user, @QueryParam("domainName") String domainName) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException, NumberFormatException, BaseException, BadLocationException {
    Query query = new Query();
    List<UserVO> alldetails = getMongoOperation().find(query, UserVO.class);
    List<String> projectlist = new ArrayList<String>();                 

    for(int i=1; i<alldetails.size();i++){
        for(int j=0; j<alldetails.get(i).getSelectedProjects().size();j++){
        if(alldetails.get(i).getSelectedProjects().get(j).getDomainName().equals(domainName)){
            projectlist.add(alldetails.get(i).getSelectedProjects().get(j).getProjectName());
        }
        }
    }
    return projectlist;
}
```

Now, i'm trying to get sprint details from levels collections based on the user collection domain & project list matched with levels.

How can i compare two collections with the list?How to populate the unique sprint details in drop down list?